# Autowire variable only if it was not set in constructor

Tags: java, spring

I have spring Bean class like this:

```
 public class A{

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;

    @Autowired
    private D d;


    public A(){
     }

    public A(B b){
      this.b = b;
    }    

    }
```

I have some spring xml bean configuration files that initialize B class, but I have also spring java configuration class that initialize **A** class like this:

```
@Configuration
public AConfigurator(){


@Bean
public A create(){
   B b = new B();
  A a = new A(b); //I set specific B instance
return a;  //my already set b property will be overried(with the bean B that has already been created in the spring context by another xml configuration) by the spring when autowiring the properties
}    
}
```

My problem is that when ***create*** metods return **A**, the spring will autowired the properties even if the properties has been already setted. It will overried the already setted **b** property. I want to autowired only the properties that were not set in the constructor. Is it possible to do it in Spring?

Comment: don't use new when you `DI` this is the goal of this pattern to avoid using new

Comment: if you only have 1 constructor in a component it is automatically autowired. Perhaps try adding a second constructor to your A class and see if this resolves the problem. Let me know if it does and we can take it from there.

Comment: I completely agree @YCF_L ... either use a DI framework, or you don't. That's like flying a Boeing 737 and having the auto-pilot going while also trying to control the thing yourself. Might not end well ...

Comment: @YCF_L There is nothing wrong with new in spring configuration class. The B is not spring Bean, doesn't have  to be spring intercepted. On the other hand, the A is the spring Bean and its created via the spring configuration class.

Comment: @Pete I forgot to put there default constructor, when I writed the question. I added the default constructor, but it doesn't solved the problem. My question is if is possible in Spring to autowired only the properties that are null, there has not been setted in constructor.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica I don't understand what you mean. I use DI framework, the configuration class is part of Sprint init context. In your @_Bean method you can create  new instance of the classes.  For example B can ba inteteger you definitely can do new Integer(10) and is nothing wrong with it, to intercept Integer to be spring bean doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest re-considering how you are using autowired and injection to achieve DI. You shouldn't allow class `A` to know ANYTHING about DI. allow all wiring to be done in your configuration class. You could accomplish this by auto-wiring the dependent classes in the `@Configuration` class. Then using them in the constructor for `A`. This ends up looking like

class A:

```
public class A{
    private B b;
    private C c;
    private D d;


    public A(B b,
            C c,
            D d){
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

Then constructing it in the `AConfigurator` class like:

```
@Configuration
class AConfigurator {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;

    @Autowired
    private D d;

    @Bean
    public A create(){
        return new A(b, c, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Spring 3 application, and A is @Component that is created by Spring when Spring auto-scan for components, so there is nothing wrong with @_Autowired annotation in A class, I can not change that class.  I only trying to find out if is possible in Spring to Autowired the property only if the property has not been set in constructor and is null.